# Python: Select Rows by value in large dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

Given a data frame df:

```
 Column A: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]

 Column B: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The goal is to conditionally replace values in column B. If column A's values exist in a set `assginedToA`, we replace the corresponding values in column B with a constant `b`.

For example: if ***b***=1  and  ***assignedToA***={1,4}, the result would be

```
Column A: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]

Column B: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

---

My code for finding the A values and write B values into it looks like this:

`df.loc[df['A'].isin(assignedToA),'B']=b`

**This code works, but it is really slow for a huge dataframe.
Do you have any advice, how to speed this process up?**

---

The dataframe df has around 5 Million rows and `assignedToA` has a maximum of 7 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find a performance improvement by dropping down to `numpy`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 3, 4, 6],
                   'B': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

def jp(df, vals, k):
    B = df['B'].values
    B[np.in1d(df['A'], list(vals))] = k
    df['B'] = B
    return df

def original(df, vals, k):
    df.loc[df['A'].isin(vals),'B'] = k
    return df

df = pd.concat([df]*100000)

%timeit jp(df, {1, 4}, 1)        # 8.55ms
%timeit original(df, {1, 4}, 1)  # 16.6ms
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The
"np.in1d()"  really helped me reducing the processing time by 60% !

Comment: @TAmoel, Excellent, feel free to accept if this resolves your question (green tick to left). But, equally, if this isn't fast enough you can wait a little longer for another answer :).